# Creating eventarc triggers for Firebase Auth events

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-run, event-arc

I tried to create a trigger for user deletes (Firebase Auth) that should call my Cloud Run instance but it seems that it doesn't trigger even after the 10 minutes. This is how I created the trigger:

```sh
gcloud eventarc triggers create on-delete-user \
  --event-filters="methodName=google.firebase.auth.user.v1.deleted" \
  --event-filters="serviceName=identitytoolkit.googleapis.com" \
  --event-filters="type=google.cloud.audit.log.v1.written" \
  --destination-run-service=grpc-v1-dev \
  --destination-run-path=/api.v1.DeleteUserEvent \
  --service-account user@projectId.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
  --location europe-west4 \
  --project projectId \
  --format json
```

What am I missing?

UPDATE:
I also tried to user the method name that I saw in the Logs.

```sh
gcloud eventarc triggers create on-delete-user-2 \
  --event-filters="type=google.cloud.audit.log.v1.written" \
  --event-filters="serviceName=identitytoolkit.googleapis.com" \
  --event-filters="methodName=google.cloud.identitytoolkit.v1.AccountManagementService.DeleteAccount" \
  --destination-run-service=grpc-v1-dev \
  --destination-run-path=/api.v1.DeleteUserEvent \
  --service-account user@projectId.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
  --location europe-west4 \
  --project projectId \
  --format json
```

UPDATE2:

I also tried to create it using the console, but still no events.

[image]

UPDATE3:
I do get events from `google.cloud.identitytoolkit.v1.AccountManagementService.DeleteAccount` in the log and my cloud instance receives the call, but the data I received has nothing to do with the model here.

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloudevents/blob/master/proto/google/events/firebase/auth/v1/events.proto

Comment: Did you try to filter the logs with your event filters? Do you have entries?

Comment: Eventually I did had events, bu the events do not conform with the data here https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloudevents/blob/master/proto/google/events/firebase/auth/v1/events.proto

Comment: Hi, could you open a bug so we can investigate? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=1030474&template=0